# Where in the Linux kernel tree can I define a new system call and a struct to write to?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I want the user to pass a pointer to a `struct` and the system call will assign values to the field in the `struct`.

Where should I define this  `struct` so that it is accessible to the userspace programs?

Comment: This would belong in a userspace library, not a system call.

Comment: @jordanm The system call function here also modifies the content in the struct. So, it should be aware of the definition of the struct. So, don't you think it should be a part of the kernel?

Comment: @Poojan jordanm is right. There needs to be a struct in kernel headers and one with the same layout (but possibly not the same type names for components) in libc. Pay attention to word sizes (e.g. `long` isn't the same size on all platforms, and the kernel and user mode programs may have differing sizes).

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. That helps a lot! So, I will define the structure twice, in kernel space as well as the userspace and make sure that there is no problem due to word size.